# CSV Value into HTML & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, csv

I have a HTML page that works great when I place numbers in manually. I would like to get it to pull data from the CSV and populate the HTML. This way my application can update the CSV file and the HTML would show the updated results without any other intervention.

Down in the  segments is where the data should show.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family:"Roadgeek2005SeriesD";
            src: url("http://panic.com/fonts/Roadgeek 2005 Series D/Roadgeek 2005 Series     D.otf");
        }
        body, * {
        }
        body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        fieldset, img {
            border: 0;
        }
        /* Settin' up the page */
        html, body, #main {
            overflow: hidden;
            /* */
        }
        body {
            color: lime;
            font-family:'Roadgeek2005SeriesD', sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }
        body, html, #main {
            background: transparent !important;
        }
        #boxnumber1 {
            width: 250px;
            height: 170px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color:lime;
            background-size: 175px 175px;
        }
        #boxnumber1 * {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #boxnumber2 {
            width: 250px;
            height: 170px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color:red;
            background-size: 175px 175px;
        }
        #boxnumber2 * {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #boxnumber3 {
            width: 250px;
            height: 170px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color:lime;
            background-size: 175px 175px;
        }
        #boxnumber3 * {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 120px;
            line-height: 120px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 28px;
            color: black;
            text-shadow:4px 4px 1px gray;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        h2 {
            width: 180px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding-top: 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: black;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="boxnumber1">
             <h2>Case Picks Left</h2>

             <h1>45</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- boxnumber1 -->
        <div id="boxnumber2">
             <h2>Pallet Picks Left</h2>

             <h1>103</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- boxnumber2 -->
        <div id="boxnumber3">
             <h2>Layer Picks Left</h2>

             <h1>4</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- boxnumber3 -->
    </div>
    <!-- main -->
</body>

</html>
```

**This is what he CSV from my application looks like:**

Work Type, Count

CASE PICKS LEFT,45

PALLET PICKS LEFT,103

LAYER PICKS LEFT,4

Answer (score 0):

I set up something similar as an example web site for a school project. I placed different Quentin Tarantino films, along with poster images and film data into a google doc spreadsheet and then linked that spreadsheet to the `HTML` page with `jQuery` and output the values form the row into the `HTML`.

The fiddle for the site is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Phlume/v7FbN/1/

The output placed on the page is from this google doc spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqglUyznS4l9dFRvbURIS3JKNDdGZi1PR2Y0QWxVM1E&u

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// get the sheet to load from the google doc (gid=0 is the default)
var q;
var t = document.URL.split('#')[1];
if(t != undefined){
    q = t.split('&')[0];
} else {
    q = 0;
}
var qtitle = "Posters";

// The published URL of your Google Docs spreadsheet as CSV with the sheet set by q
var csvURL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AqglUyznS4l9dFRvbURIS3JKNDdGZi1PR2Y0QWxVM1E&='+q+'&output=csv';
// process the google docs JSON string with Yahoos YQL service:
var yqlURL =    "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'"+encodeURIComponent(csvURL)+"'%20and%20columns%3D'id%2Cimage%2Cheadline%2Cdescription%2Cmmc%2Citem'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?";


        function CleanBr(s){
            if (s === null){
                console.log("s is null: " + s);
                return s;
            } else {
                console.log("s is: " + s);
                return s.replace(/""/g,'"')
                        .replace(/^"|"$/g,'')
                        .replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
            } 
        };



$.getJSON(yqlURL,function(msg){

    var i = 1;
    var csl = $('<div>');

    // Looping through all the entries in the CSV file:
    $.each(msg.query.results.row,function(){

        var poster =  this.id || "no-id-00" + i;
        var image = CleanBr(this.image);
        var headline = CleanBr(this.headline);
        var role = CleanBr(this.description);
        var url_mmc = CleanBr(this.mmc);
        var actor = CleanBr(this.item);

        if (image != ''){
            // has image
            csl.append('<div id=' + poster + ' class="poster" >\n\n<span class="item2"><img src="' + poster + '" border="0"  alt=""/></span><div class="title">'+ url_mmc +'</b></div><div class="actor"><b>' + actor +'</b> </div><div class="role"><span style="font-size:14px;"><b>QT&rsquo;s role:</b><br>' + role +' </div><div class="year"><b>' + image +'</b></div><span><a class="imdb" href="' + headline + '" target="_blank">IMDB link</a></span></div></div><br><br>');
        }
        i++
    });

    function changeClass(){
    //var changed = inumber;
    document.getElementById(changed).className = 'item-2';
    }

    var copiable = $(csl).html().replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    $('#Core').html(csl); // print the list:
    $('#ctrlc').text(copiable); // print the code       
    $("#status").html((i-1) + " Entries"); // print the status
    $("#page").html(qtitle); // print the sheet title


});
});
```

Comment: How do I get the HTML to call from this java script?